# Smack library and PHP

Tags: php, smack

I read some examples to connect to GTalk by using Smack library. But all examples are in Java. 
can Smack library use along with PHP?

thank u

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Java bridge for achiving this.

```
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/
```

Also there is another bridge for Zend Server:

```
http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/
```

PS. Bridge is a protocol, not a extension. It connects to a Java service from Apache,IIS like SOAP, RPC.

Comment: i've found this..how do u think?http://www.thedeveloperday.com/googletalk-integration-with-php/

Comment: I suggested you a Java bridge, because your question is about Smack otherwise, of course you can write your own Jabber client on php. XMPPHP is not stable and has many bugs.